# multiple submit buttons with different names one action php

Tags: php, html

he i'm trying to select all the record with a certain date out of my database when a submit is hit but the submits are created out of dates from the database. like

```
<?php
        echo "<form method='post' action=''><table class='turflist'>
              <tr>
              <th>Turf list Date</th>
              </tr>";

        foreach($backup_results as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><button class='turfButton' type='submit' name='". $row['date'] ."'>" . $row['date'] . "</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table></form>";
    ?>
```

now i want to check if the submit of a date for example 2017-03-02 isset and then select all the record with the date 2017-03-02 out of the database. 
But the same query should also work with the date 2016-20-03 for example. 
Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can on submit check for each individual name... so:

```
if(isset($_POST['2017-03-02'])){

}
```

But a better way to do this would be dynamically build radio buttons instead with ONE name, dynamic values. THEN have ONE submit button. Like so:

```
?php
    echo "<form method='post' action=''><table class='turflist'>
          <tr>
          <th>Turf list Date</th>
          </tr>";

    foreach($backup_results as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='dates' class='turfButton'  value='". $row['date'] ."'>" . $row['date'] . "/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />";
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $date = $_POST['dates'];
  // RUN YOUR MYSQL QUERY HERE USING $date, which would be the selected radio button
}
?>
```

Comment: this is a dynamic data

Comment: I'm aware, you're dynamically assigning the value to each radio button. You don't want multiple submit buttons on a form. But dynamically assign a radio button a value, then on submit you pull in the value of the chosen radio button, maybe I'm misreading your question..

Comment: That's not my question, but the title says multiple submits, and the button is created inside a loop,

Comment: and your code will only work when he clicks the button `2017-03-02` what about other buttons?

Comment: It will when he clicks another other radio button and clicks submit again.

Comment: if he have 100 dates, with ur code he will need to write `if(isset($_POST['2017-03-02'])){

}`  100 times

Comment: The first example yes. My second example, my suggested example, no. He'd type if isset submit, then use the post variable for the radio buttons.

Comment: it wasn't exactly the best worded either. My solution (2nd) would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you stored your date in the table. but however the `$row['date']` is dynamic therefore you can just assign `$row['date'];` to a new variable. when the form button loads your the name because what ever that is in that variable, so you just need to check if that variable isset and fetch everything that equals that variable.

```
<?php
echo "<form method='post' action=''><table class='turflist'>
              <tr>
              <th>Turf list Date</th>
              </tr>";

foreach ($backup_results as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";

      $datebtn = strtotime($row['date']);

    echo "<td><button class='turfButton' type='submit' name='" .$datebtn . "'>" . $datebtn  . "</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table></form>";


if (isset($_POST["$datebtn"])) {

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl  WHERE DATE(DateField) = ? ");
    $sql->bind_param("s",$datebtn);
    $sql->execute();

  //continue fetch ur results

}

?>
```